# Why am I getting an "unable to update url base from redirection" error in Source Tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Anytime I try to do anything (push, pull, clone a new repo) in sourcetree I get the following error:

```
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no- 
optional-locks ls-remote [**REPO URL**]
Output: 
Error: fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: [**REPO URL**]/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: http://10.8.1.31:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws- 
session=18446744073333433429
```

It was working fine for me yesterday, but now this

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

Your are using git over http, your traffic goes through a forcepoint websense (an http firewall / filter), and your traffic is filtered.
You either need to ask your administrator to accept the traffic, or connect from elsewhere.

Comment: How would I connect from somewhere else?